# Grails cascade delete up the inheritance tree

Tags: inheritance, grails, grails-orm

I have the following classes:

```
abstract class Foo {
    String x
    ...

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    String y
    ...
}
```

And the delete action in FooController looks like this:

```
def delete() {
    def f = Foo.get(params.id)
    f.delete()
}
```

In my particular scenario, **Foo.get(params.id)** returns an object of type Bar, so when I call **f.delete()**, Grails deletes the record out of the Bar table, but not from the Foo table. This causes all sorts of problems because Grails has only half-deleted the object record.

What is the best way to make sure that the delete cascades up the inheritance hierarchy when not using tablePerHierarchy?

There are valid reasons we have chosen not to use TablePerHierarchy, so I can't change that.

Also, calling the following code also results in the Bar record being deleted, but not Foo:

```
Foo.executeUpdate("delete Foo f where f.id = :fid", [fid: Long.parseLong(params.id)])
```